# OnCreate ends before data can be retrieved asynchronously

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask, oncreate

I am working on some code that will pull JSON information from Facebook and place it in an EditText view. The problem I am encountering is that since the function I'm calling to retrieve the data is an Async function, the data is being retrieved AFTER my onCreate function for my activity ends, so the text cannot be updated since at the time it is null. **How can I make sure my OnCreate method doesn't end until the data is retrieved?**

Here is my Activity Class:

```
public class PersonalInfoMain extends AppCompatActivity implements GraphService.OnDownloadComplete {

    public EditText mName;
    public String name;

    String mValue, mField;

    private static final String TAG = "PersonalInfoMain";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starts");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal_info_main);

        mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);

        //Calling GraphService class
        GraphService mGraphService = new GraphService(this);
        mField = "name";
        mGraphService.execute(mField);
        mName.setText(name);
    }
}

    //My Callback function located in the same activity:
    @Override
    public void onDownloadComplete(String s) {
            name = s;
    }
```

Here is my class I labelled GraphService to pull information from Facebook:

```
public class GraphService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

private static final String TAG = "GraphService";

private String mField;
private String mValue;

private final OnDownloadComplete mCallback;

public interface OnDownloadComplete{
    void onDownloadComplete(String data);
}

public GraphService(OnDownloadComplete callback){
    mCallback = callback;
}

@Override
public String doInBackground(final String... params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: starts");

    mField = params[0];

    //Beginning of Facebook implementation
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                        mValue = object.getString(mField);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    );

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", mField);
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
    return mValue;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if(mCallback != null){
        mCallback.onDownloadComplete(s);
    }
}
```

My Android Monitor displays this workflow:

```
D/MainActivity: onCreate: starts
D/MainActivity: isLoggedIn: starts
D/MainActivity: isLoggedIn: ends
D/MainActivity: onCreate: ends
D/PersonalInfoMain: onCreate: starts
D/PersonalInfoMain: onCreate: name = null
D/GraphService: doInBackground: starts
D/PersonalInfoMain: onCreate: ends
D/PersonalInfoMain: onResume: starts
D/PersonalInfoMain: onResume: name = null
D/GraphService: doInBackground: ends
D/PersonalInfoMain: onResume: ends
D/GraphService: onPostExecute: starts
D/PersonalInfoMain: onDownloadComplete: starts
D/PersonalInfoMain: onDownloadComplete: ends
D/GraphService: onPostExecute: ends
D/GraphService: onCompleted: starts, JSON object = {"name":"Tom"}, response = {"name":"Tom"}
D/GraphService: onCompleted: json object:{"name":"Tom"}
D/GraphService: onCompleted: ends
```

As you can see, my .setText() method in my activity sets it to a null value because the Async task (onCompleted() method) hasn't returned the data yet. **How can I make sure my OnCreate method doesn't end until the data is retrieved?**

I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and **you should not** as you are doing Asynchronous network request. Better you just call setText method once you have required data from the network call.

//My Callback function located in the same activity:

```
@Override
public void onDownloadComplete(String s) {
        mName.setText(s);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, I always heard that short actions like a network request should be called Asynchronously. Can you please explain why I should not do this?

I have tried your code, and it still doesn't update mName, because the JSON retrieval code is being called after the onDownloadComplete function ends, (as you can see in the Logcat)

Comment: Yes I just found out you are again making Asynchronous GraphRequest inside doInBackground, so in that case you calling return even before you are getting result from the request. Here you do not need AsyncTask as you can directly call GraphRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to move the code from your onDownloadComplete() to onPostExecute(). Personally I don't think it's necessary to use the

public interface OnDownloadComplete{

```
void onDownloadComplete(String data);
```

}

here.

After the execution of the method doInBackground(), the result of it (mValue) will be passed to onPostExecute(String s) as the s.

In onPostExecute(), you can update your UI.

This is my first answer here. If anything is wrong, please tell me.